# SPI From AdaFruit Trinket to ST7789 Display

Tags: arduino, screen, microcontroller, spi, adafruit

I am working with the ST7789 Display and my ultimate goal is to display images on the screen using the built in MicroSD slot. I have a AdaFruit Trinket 3v that I'm using for the primary logic but I cannot seem to figure out how to program the trinket to communicate with the display.

From my research, I've been able to solder the wires in place to set up an SPI compatible connection between the two using the #1 and #0 pins on the trinket along with reset pin which are connected to the SI, SO, and Reset on the display in that order. I am writing the code in C++ using VS Code and the PlatformIO plugin to add the appropriate libraries for the trinket and ST7789 display.

Comment: You'll also need to connect to pin 2, SCK, because SPI needs a clock as well.  Connect the grounds together also. And the display needs a power connection, too. This page might help... https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-1-3-and-1-54-240-x-240-wide-angle-tft-lcd-displays  Have fun!